# Strange image alignment within div when sizes are animated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've written simple webpage with javascript, which attempts to scale an element from the centre of the page over time after a click. It works fine for the svg element I tested.

But when I use an image, it starts off outside of the div, (which is centred) and slowly converges towards it as it gets bigger, after which it is centred as it should be.
The only results I can find are related to overflow settings, but even with overflow set to hidden the image is still outside of the div and visible. The div is the first thing to be resized, so it is always big enough for the image.

Could it be because of the small size values I am using, or is it a problem with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <style>
    body {
     margin:0;
    }
    #maindiv {
     position:absolute;
     background-color:#141414;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    #face {
    width:109px;
    /* height: auto !important;  */
    }
    #facediv { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 50%; 
     left: 50%;
     }
    </style>

    <script>

    function sizeUpdate (elem){
        var sf = 1

        function frame(){

            sf++                                                                <!-- increment scale factor
            var fwidth = 0.1;
            var scaledwidthface = (fwidth * sf);                                <!-- scaled width - width-constant*scale-factor
            var face_var =document.getElementById("face");
            var facediv_var = document.getElementById("facediv");
            facediv_var.style.width = ""+scaledwidthface+"px";                  <!-- set containing div to same width as object
            facediv_var.style.marginLeft = ""+(-1 * scaledwidthface/2 )+"px";   <!-- set the container div to x-offset half object-width (centres horizontally)
            face_var.style.width = ""+scaledwidthface+"px";                     <!-- set width of object
            var face_ht = face_var.clientHeight;                                <!-- get integer-form of object height (?)
            facediv_var.style.height = ""+face_ht+"px";                         <!-- set container div to same height as object
            facediv_var.style.marginTop = ""+(-1*face_ht/2)+"px";               <!--set container div y-offset half object-height (centres vertically)

            if (sf == 500)
                clearInterval(id)                                               <!--stop when incr reaches this maximum
        }

        var id = setInterval(frame, 50)

    }
    </script>
 </head>


    <body>
        <div id="maindiv" onclick="sizeUpdate(this.children[0])">
            <div id="facediv">
                <img id="face" src="http://goo.gl/6xLiC">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to close the comment? `<!-- ???? -->`

Comment: @A.S.Roma That's not a js comment.  I assume OP inserted it for our benefit only

Comment: i know it is html comment.

Comment: Yeah sorry, its because I used the comment menu option in notepad++ (probably incorrectly but it didn't seem to make a difference)
I'll edit the code thanks.
(The weird behaviour still remains)

Comment: can you upload to jsfiddle, its is easier to see what are you talking about when you have a visual

Comment: seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PZazq/show/ though it is off center at first (no negative margins initially)

Comment: Yeah that is my problem, do you know why there are no negative margins at that point?
Edit: I know it seems like a non-issue but its a problem because it needs to be aligned with other elements as it scales

Comment: @dnv because they are being set by the javascript in the code.  Your image is still at 50% 50% (this corresponds to the top left corner of the image).  Thus you need negative margins of half the width and height of the image for it to center correctly.

Comment: Oh you mean before the click, sorry yes i havent coded that part yet.
But my problem is that if you look at the animation in the inspector you'll see that the cat starts animating outside of its div container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that images default to inline display rather than block.  This means that images carry over the attributes of letters and words (font-size and line-height).  The discrepancy you were seeing (illustrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsKeX/)) can be corrected by simply applying the following `display:block` rule

```
#facediv img {
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsKeX/1)

I should have noticed sooner :P

EDIT:  Out of morbid curiosity, I made the equivalent with the image still as an inline element setting the line height and font sizes to 0px.  See it working in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsKeX/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Really glad it was this simple :]

Comment: @dnv You're welcome! Always glad to help.  Also, thanks you! with this answer I now have enough rep to be a trusted user on SO. :)